# Component ID in ui:repeat problems

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm trying to `render` a grandparent component.
The code:

```
<h:form prependId="false>
<h:panelGroup id="outer_panel">
    <ui:repeat var="curr" value="#{bean.map}">
        <h:panelGroup id="inner_panel">
            <h:commandButton value="Remove" action="actionThing" >
                <f:ajax render="outer_panel" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

I get an exception:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Component with id:outer_panel not found
```

Tried to add the index to the id, which didn't work neither:

```
<h:form prependId="false>
<h:panelGroup id="outer_panel">
    <ui:repeat var="curr" value="#{bean.map}" varStatus="loop">
        <h:panelGroup id="inner_panel">
            <h:commandButton value="Remove" action="actionThing" >
                <f:ajax render="#{loop.index+1}:outer_panel" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Any idea why the ID is not found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not found because you used a relative client ID in `render` attribute. It becomes relative to the closest parent [naming container](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) component. In this case, that's the `<ui:repeat>` (it prepends generated client ID of the children with the row index). So the component with ID `outer_panel` has to be inside the `<ui:repeat>` in order to get it to work. However, the `outer_panel` is *actually* outside it.

You need to specify an absolute client ID instead of a relative client ID. To make it absolute (so that it will basically scan from the view root on), prefix the client ID with `:`.

```
<f:ajax render=":outer_panel" />
```

For the case that you didn't use `prependId="false"` on the `<h:form>`, then you should have used

```
<f:ajax render=":form_id:outer_panel" />
```

instead.

Comment: would, `inner_panel` be refrenced as `:outer_panel:inner:panel` or `inner_panel`? I'm asking because, in practice, `out_panel` is contained in other `h:panelGroup`s. Also, when printing the id of `outer_panel` (using `#{component.clientId}`) I get `j_id594943238_6609e93f:0:outer_panel` (As you may assume, there are other `<ui:repeat>` components containing `outer_panel`. Perhaps I should have mentioned this earlier...

Comment: It's in the same parent naming container as `<f:ajax>`, so just `render="inner_panel"` should do.